# jspm package dependency order

Tags: angularjs, jspm

So jspm working great when scripts are not being bundled, but on bundling, even though in my config.js file I have the following, which states that angular is a dependency on angular-ui-bootstrap, it doesn't seem to be taken into account on bundling

```
"npm:angular-ui-bootstrap@0.14.3": {
  "angular": "npm:angular@1.5.0"
}
```

the bundling results in a single js file where angular is defined (line 49,098) **after** angular-ui-boostrap (line 14,991), so when I open a browser on the initial landing page, I get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

It's not making sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you